# weight of fully loaded RAM

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I had read a post 
[Is a hard drive heavier when it is full?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31326/is-a-hard-drive-heavier-when-it-is-full) 
It states, there is some difference in the weight of fully loaded hard drive and an empty hard drive due to different orientation of magnetic dipoles. Now, does a RAM or any other volatile storage device, completely filled with binary numbers weight more than an empty one??

Comment: The answer is also yes, since RAM is a temporary storage, it just stores until your clear the RAM or restart your computer. It is also related to flash memory, I guess. http://www.ellipsix.net/blog/2011/11/how-much-does-data-weigh-in-flash-memory.html

Comment: In this article, the proof has given considering a thermodynamically isolated environment (someone has also comment there), does things change if we consider room temperature ????

Comment: The electrons would have a higher energy at a temperature above absolute zero. But I would argue that that extra energy is due to the nonzero temperature, and wouldn't really be considered weight of the data itself. Incidentally, DRAM (the kind used in modern computers) uses charged vs. uncharged capacitors to store data, rather than transistors, but the principle is not too dissimilar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the difference would be inappreciable. Vsauce had calculated the weight of all the information on the Internet and it only adds up to a grain of sand.

Comment: will there be any difference if we change thermodynamic conditions??? And how the energy-mass conservation law is satisfied ???
I know this require some explanation but if you could tell something in brief.