# Does the weight of a computer go up as information is added to it?

Tags: electromagnetism, mass, electrons, matter, computer

This probably sounds really naive. But, a strange discussion came up on Quora about computers possibly weighing more when information is added to them.

I tried looking around but couldn't find a definitive answer. There are a few threads where people have tried to ask something similar.

1) http://www.thenakedscientists.com/forum/index.php?topic=38844.0

2) http://www.lolhappens.com/27706/does-a-computers-weight-increase-as-information-is-added-to-the-hard-drive/

Both threads have people arguing about the possibilities, but I'm sure a more definitive, and painfully detailed answer must exist. I hope you have a good laugh and then help me out!

I don't have the rep to post more than two links so I'll just put the original thread in the comments.

Thank you!

Comment: The original thread on Quora: http://www.quora.com/Does-the-weight-of-the-computer-increase-when-data-is-stored-in-it

Comment: So you just increased the mass of the Stackexchange servers... Bad you!

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31326/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53279/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic [Let me predict, you are about to protect this question as well, right?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/112866/if-im-floating-in-space-and-i-turn-on-a-flashlight-will-i-accelerate#comment232884_112866)

Comment: @AwalGarg: Moderator protection is not used on questions with no answers.

Comment: @Jim: Your comment probably should be an answer

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks! I think this should be marked as a duplicate though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't add matter when you store information. Unless you do so by plugging in a drive. Additionally, since there are about the same amount of 1's and 0's running around in a computer when it's drive is empty as when it is full, and since the states of the electrons in the physical drive (ie how info is stored) makes a lack of information weigh the same as a quantity of information, the weight of a computer does not change. Not in any figure-out-able way. But it does change between off and on states